# Sharepoint 2013 // Iteration in list

Tags: 2013, list, email

I have list with below structure

```
Name   Email
ABC    ABC@bt.com
XYZ    XYZ@bt.com
WER    WER@bt.com
```

I would like to be able to send an email to all the email addresses which are on this list. The entries in this list will increase gradually so I want whenever an email is sent it should be sent to all those are under the Email column.

I wasn't able to find an easier straightforward solution to this problem.
Please assist with your expert guidance.

If this can't be done, is there a way I can dynamically add users to a dummy group when a new entry is created in this list based upon any condition. For example, if a user entry is added to the list with designation as "consultant", that email should be automatically added to the consultant dummy group which I could later use to send email in a SharePoint workflow.

OR

Is there a way I could do something like this

```
Name   Email                    Variable
ABC    ABC@bt.com     abc@bt.com;xyz@bt.com;wer@bt.com
XYZ    XYZ@bt.com
WER    WER@bt.com
```

Whenever a new entry is added to this list, workflow to be able to concatenate all the email addresses to a single field which can be again used to send emails to all the addresses ?

Thanks for your help in anticipation.

### UPDATE1:-

I tried the solution with the below workflow

[image: I am copying email address from current list to variable temp, it works and logs in the history]

[image: Here I am updating Title value in Email master with [%Current Item:Title%];[%Variable: temp%] but it only holds the last entry]

For example, if I add first entry as abcd@xyz.com, it will be coped into the new Email master list. Then if I add another entry in the parent list as qwer@xyz.com, the final result in email master would be ;qwer@bt.com.

It just keeps the last email entry with a preceeding ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another custom list and name it `EmailMaster`. Let it have the `Title` field only.

Now add a new item to the list and leave the `Title` field blank. *You might need to make the field not required.* The `ID` of the list item will be 1. Now using SharePoint Designer hide this list from the browser.

Next attach a workflow to the `Email` list you have. On new item create use an `Update List Item` activity and update the `EmailMaster` - `Title` field by concatenating the new value to the existing value in the `Title` field.

Next use the `Send Email` activity and use the `Title` field value of `ID=1` to retrieve the sender's list.

Comment: Thanks Amal,

How do I go about this part of your response

Next attach a workflow to the Email list you have. On new item create use an Update List Item activity and update the EmailMaster - Title field by concatenating the new value to the existing value in the Title field.

How do I write the concatenation workflow to concatenate the new value with the existing value in the list and updating it ?

Comment: First read the value from list into a workflow variable.. Then use calculation activities for concatenation

Comment: I tried your solution but it works partially. Could you please check what am I missing here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add all users (Email ID) depends on your **designation**("consultant") to a group/different groups with Workflow and shoot email to group/groups.
This is possible.
Hope it could be help you.

Comment: Thanks Ram, there is no option in a workflow to add a user email id to a group dynamically OOB.